# How do I set up pulseaudio's RTP client to listen to a vlc RTP server?

Tags: pulseaudio, vlc

Pulse audio provides the ability to load an rtp client which listens for SAP broadcasts,

```
pactl load-module module-rtp-recv
```

However, I can't get the combination or arguments right for `vlc` to announce on sap and stream to it. Could someone help take me through the process?

Comment: I believe the correct answer is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392728/is-pulseaudio-able-to-receive-rtp-multicast-from-any-source