# Is Pulseaudio able to receive RTP Multicast from any source?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, multicast

Been attempting to get Pulseaudio to receive an RTP stream from VLC. I can get it to receive a TCP audio stream no problem - the pi running Pulse is receiving the multicast data as expected, but when running --verbose I just see it sitting suspended. sap_address is configured to the correct network and rcv is uncommented, is it listening on all ports since there is not one defined? Does it need to have CIDR after the address?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you tried (you didn't specify), but I can get two pulseaudio servers to communicate via multicast RTP in the following way.

On the sender,

```
pacmd load-module module-rtp-send source=name_of_mic_source destination_ip=232.43.211.230 inhibit_auto_suspend=always
```

where `name_of_mic_source` is a source connected to a microphone for testing (use `pamcd list-sources | grep name:` to see names, ignore the angular brackets).

On the receiver,

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtpsink
pacmd load-module module-rtp-recv sink=rtpsink sap_address=232.43.211.230
```

This creates a "null" sink I can monitor with `pavucontrol` to verify the noises I making in front of the mic get through. Wireshark verifies the packets are really multicast.

It also works without `destination_ip` resp. `sap_address`, in which case the default `224.0.0.56` multicast group will be used. However this group is link-local, so it won't be routed, and both computers must be on the same segment for it to work.

This was a test setup. To forward sound from `vlc` etc., I'd create the null sink on the sender, let `vlc` play into this sink, use the associated `rtpsink.monitor` source for `module-rtp-send`, and connect `module-rtp-recv` directly to an audible sink on the receiver.

I haven't tried this with an RTP-stream directly produced by `vlc`, but if you describe your setup, I can test this, too. If something goes wrong, it should be east to compare the SDP/SAP announcements with Wireshark to see if the problem is there.

Comment: Well forgetting VLC for a moment as I was just using that to create a multicast stream, I am attempting to take a USB Audio device's line in on one Pi, RTP the signal out multicast, and receive on multiple units in a house. I'm new to Pulse but it appears there is a loop through feature I can utilize - I am just trying to figure out what my default.pa should look like on both sides, as I am obviously missing something. At the moment I'm not having luck getting the server to actually send out Multicast data - my default.pa file contains a line similar to your pacmd example.

Comment: To clarify, I see RTP uncompressed audio traffic in Wireshark but receive nothing when connecting to the stream using VLC or Pulseaudio on the other end.

Comment: Hit enter too soon, full comment was  To clarify, I see RTP uncompressed audio traffic in Wireshark but receive nothing when connecting to the stream using VLC or Pulseaudio on the other end using the following command on the "server"   (apologies for formatting here)  pacmd load-module module-rtp-send source=alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo.monitor destination_ip=224.0.0.57 port=5001 inhibit_auto_suspend=always

Comment: It's difficult for me to debug this without everything in front of me. You did create the null sink on the receiver, you monitor it with `pavucontrol`, you start `module-rtp-recv` with the correct IP, and you see the SDP/SAP announcement + the RTP traffic on the receiving machine in Wireshark? If yes, I don't know where the problem is, it "should" work.

Comment: I've actually gotten things working, realized I was off in a couple places. Now if I can get the multicast flood to stop when I'm not playing audio, it would be perfect....with inhibit_auto_suspend=never it just suspends my input and two sources after a second - "always", and it constantly fires off multicast traffic.

Comment: I guess that depends how you detect "not playing audio". Loading and unloading `module-rtp-send` via a script is the easiest variant I can think of. `inhibit_auto_suspend` does a different thing than you think it does, see [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index7h2).